# How to run and deploy AWS's XGBoost MNIST sample notebook on SageMaker?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, encoding, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to use [Kubernetes SageMaker Operations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/simplify-machine-learning-inference-on-kubernetes-with-amazon-sagemaker-operators/) with the XGBoost MNIST AWS's [example](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/xgboost_mnist/xgboost_mnist.ipynb).

Before I am enabling Kubernetes SageMaker Ops, I have deployed the XGBoost MNIST example via SageMaker WebUI itself and tried to access the endpoint via awscli:

```
$ aws sagemaker-runtime invoke-endpoint \
    --region eu-west-1 \
    --endpoint-name DEMO-XGBoostEndpoint-2020-11-20-06-26-30 \
    --body $(seq 784 | xargs echo | sed 's/ /,/g') \
    >(cat) \
    --content-type text/csv > /dev/null
```

However, I am encountering the following decoding error:

```
An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (415) from model with message "Loading csv data failed with Exception, please ensure data is in csv format:
 <class 'UnicodeDecodeError'>
 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 0: invalid continuation byte". See https://xxxx.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=xxxxx#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/DEMO-XGBoostEndpoint-2020-11-20-06-26-30 in account XXX for more information.
```

And in the log I can see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/algorithm_mode/serve_utils.py", line 102, in parse_content_data
    decoded_payload = payload.strip().decode("utf-8")
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/algorithm_mode/serve_utils.py", line 102, in parse_content_data decoded_payload = payload.strip().decode("utf-8")
```

When I go to the source code of [sagemaker_xgboost_container](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-xgboost-container/blob/master/src/sagemaker_xgboost_container/algorithm_mode/serve_utils.py#L102) I can see that they expect UTF-8 format:

```
        decoded_payload = payload.strip().decode("utf-8")
```

My `locale` seems fine and I am really not sure what else could go wrong:

```
$ locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Your provided csv in all likelihood is not encoded in unicode (it's likely iso-8859-1 or latin-1); therefore, the encoding fails when trying to convert from unicode to utf-8.

Comment: @JacobTurpin, not sure I am understanding. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted AWS support and apparently this is a bug in `awscli`. Here is a revised excerpt from their long and detailed answer.

> This is an encoding issue with AWSCLI v2. For now, you can proceed
> with AWSCLI v1.18 as a temporary solution.

I also verified it works with aws-cli/1.18.185:

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.18.185 Python/3.8.3 Linux/4.19.104-microsoft-standard botocore/1.19.25

$ aws sagemaker-runtime invoke-endpoint \
>     --region eu-west-1 \
>     --endpoint-name DEMO-XGBoostEndpoint-2020-11-20-06-26-30 \
>     --body $(seq 784 | xargs echo | sed 's/ /,/g') \
>     >(cat) \
>     --content-type text/csv > /dev/null
8.0%
```

In AWS cli v2.1.21 amazon added the `--cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out` option and this should work as it worked with AWS cli v1.18:

```
aws sagemaker-runtime invoke-endpoint \
>     --region <aws-region> \
>     --endpoint-name <you-endpoint-name> \
>     --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out \
>     --body $(seq 784 | xargs echo | sed 's/ /,/g') \
>     >(cat) \
>     --content-type text/csv > /dev/null
```